# Linux script to kill process listening on a particular port

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a process that listens on a TCP port (?0003). From time to time it crashes - badly. It stops working, but continues hogging the port for some time, so I can't even restart it. I'm looking to automate this.

What I do right now is:

```
netstat -ntlp |grep -P "\*\:\d0003"
```

To see what the PID is and then:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Does anyone have a script (or EXE for that matter) that would link the two steps together, ie. parse the PID from the first command and pass it to the second?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/322363/how-do-i-find-and-kill-process-running-on-a-certain-port

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also can do by that way :

```
kill -9 $( lsof -i:?0003 -t )
```

Comment: Very elegant!
I often use things like lsof -ni:80,443 - but wasn`t aware of the switch -t 
thanks!

Comment: Indeed. the `?` wildcard doesn't work on my version of lsof, but multiple -i options work. Changing the accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 5):

```
kill $(netstat -ntpl 2>/dev/null | egrep "^tcp  .*:[0-9]0003"|awk '{print $7}'|cut -d / -f 1 )
```

You may do `kill -9` instead of you think the -9 is required. I redirect the netstat stderr because it omits a message when run as non-root which is unimportant for this purpose. I include tcp in the regex to filter out tcp6.

Comment: Using back-apostrophes is deprecated, because this leads to quoting-related problems and mistakes. Switch to `$()` and turn using it into a habit.

Answer (score 3):

there you go, one line for you

```
netstat -ntlp | awk '$4~/:*0003$/{gsub(/\/.*/,"",$NF);cmd="kill -9 "$NF;system(cmd)}'
```

Comment: +1 Works very nicely, thank you. I'm accepting Peter Lyons' answer, just because it's one line and can be pasted into the command-line more easily. :)

Comment: Alright then, another +1 here on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the `python` command is just the first term in the full command, right?
If you have the name of the script being run you can look at something like `pgrep -f`

If you are sure of uniqueness, you can also use the related `pkill -f`

Answer (score 0):

What about `killall <command>` are there more than one of these processes?

If that don't work try:

```
PID=`netstat -ntlp |grep -P "\*\:\d0003"`; kill -9 $PID
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: No, there's just one, and I can't go by the process name, because it's typically just "python" or "java".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the fuser command with the -k and -n options may help. Say "man fuser" for more info.